# Cannot see python print statements when I execute kubectl logs <pod>

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, kubernetes

I'm working on a simple python 3 application that would be using print statements.
It is crutial for me to see the logs when i execute kubectl log command.
However, the logs are never present.
It looks like the application may not be running in the pod.
When i'm executing kubectl --it exexc and go in to pod I land up in working directory, then when i manually execute python myApp.py it is printing the logs.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "/.main.py" ]
```

For a simple example I can use a piece of code which just prints:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    print("Im printing ...")
    sleep(10)
```

My pod definition look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: logbox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: logbox
      image: <8888888888888888>logbox:0.0.1
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      stdin: true
      args:
        - sh
        - -c
        - sleep infinity
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that the `args` commands in the pod definition are overriding the Dockerfile `CMD` command, I'd give it a try without the definition args or by matching them (so the args calls the `python ./main.py`

Comment: This did not help at the first time. However, when I changed  ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED for 0 to 1. The logs started. In some other cases, I was getting CrashLoopBackOffs before those args, so I thud that they are necessary in order for pod to stay running. Thanks again !!!